# How to share models between different MVC websites?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 seperate areas for my ASP.NET MVC 3 website - Admin (Intranet website) and Client (Internet website).

The Model (business and data access layer) will be used by both websites. The websites will be hosted on seperate servers. So, the folder will not be shared.
So, I am planning to create the DLL of the Model and put the DLL in the Bin Folder of both website and use it.

I hope this will keep my UI neat and less code as well.

Now, my doubts are:

1. Do I need to create a Class Library project to create the DLL of the Model or do I need to use and MVC web application project to create the DLL?
2. Where should I put the web config? Hope I need in both Model and also in UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your abstracted business logic should be in a separate class library project. You can then reference this project from web apps in the same solution or compile it and reference it as a DLL. Your web.config file(s) will still live in your web project(s).

To add settings for your class library in your web project, use configuration sections:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="My.Class.Library.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <My.Class.Library.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="SettingName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>SettingValue</value>
        </setting>
    </My.Class.Library.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Comment: In the Web Config of the UI what changes should I make to fetch data from the DLL instead of the Entity. At the moment my connection string looks like this - <add name="myContext" connectionString="data source=....;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="myEntities"
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.myDBName.csdl|res://*/Models.myDBName.ssdl|res://*/Models.myDBName.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string...MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @user2215116 As far as I know, your class library should use the relevant connectionstrings from your web.config file by default.

Comment: So, do you mean I should have the above connection string in the UI and then pass it to the Business Logic layer and then to the Data Accesss Layer through the DLL each time when I want to access the DataBase (for each inser/select function)?

Comment: No, I mean you should put the connectionstrings in your web application and then just use them in your class library as you would normally.

Comment: My code looks something like this - 
The Action in my Controller: 
        public ActionResult InsertEmployeeName(string empname)   {  
 
  bool feedback = DLL_EmployeeElement.InsertEmployee(empname);
            return RedirectToAction("SavedEMPLIST", "Employee"});  
 
      } 
The Insert Method in my Class Library (DLL):
        public static bool InsertEmployeeName(string empname)        
  { bool feedback = false;           
 
  using (var context = new myEntities()){             
  try{ ...  context.SaveChanges();feedback = true;          
}catch (Exception e)       
{}
}return feedback;}

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to create a Class Library project to create the DLL of the Model

Yes, a separate class library shared between the 2 web applications is the best approach.

> Do I need to use and MVC web application project to create the DLL (looking for the best approach)?

No, the ASP.NET MVC could contain only the views. Do not reference and reuse a web application for common logic in other applications.

> Where should I put the web config?

Each ASP.NET MVC web application should have its own web.config.

Comment: Hi Darin, Hope I need use an App.config in the Class Library to put the connection string in the Class Library Project. After adding reference to the DLL in the UI, hope I can delete the Model folder from the UI; then I will have only the Views and Model Folder in the UI. Where should I put my View Models - is it in the Class Library and refer it?

Comment: There's no such notion as App.config in a class library. The configuration file should live only in the application you are deploying, in your case that's an ASP.NET application, so you should use a web.config