# Share model and dbcontext between mvc and console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, console-application

I have an MVC project and a Console application that use the same database. I currently duplicate the model and dbcontext in both solutions, so I would like to just keep them in one place. I saw similar questions:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673937/how-to-share-a-database-between-asp-net-mvc-5-application-and-net-console-appli) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338069/how-to-share-models-between-different-mvc-websites). I'm somehow not convinced to using Nuget for this, so I would rather use a class library. I'm not sure though if especially for MVC there would be some downsides of having dbcontext separated from MVC app? Does this make sense and how would I then reference the context from web/app configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to split your solution in layers, for example:

- Domain Layer (Entities, Interfaces for Repositories and Services)
- Data Layer (Repositories)
- IoC Layer (Ninject and all modules)
- Presentation Layer (Web Project)
- Console Layer

[image]

With this approach you can reuse your Entities and Repositories (DbContext and ohter classes resposible to access data) in several layers, even when your project grow, and believe me, your project your grow.

In your Web and Console Layer you reference the DataLayer, and then you can access your context from there.

Try always to follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles, for a better and reusable code.

Comment: Hi Pedro, yes the SOLID part is clear at least in theory, that's why I want to do it :) With layers - how do you see this physically aside from conceptually?

Comment: Thank you, though I'm not sure this will work for me. I want to run the console app in the cloud without all the website overhead. Actually it just has one exe in the debug folder and I'm not so sure what this exe is executing, everything, just the console part ?

Comment: @Turo: You add project references in your console app to the class library projects you need (Domain, Data, etc.). The DLLs from these compiled projects will be added to your console app when it's compiled, so all you have to deploy is the console app. Everything it needs, even from other projects, comes along for the ride.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have the same requirement, I have an extra service layer where I create functions to interact with DB. I need to use that layer in console app too but I have to replicate the web.config in console's app app.config for DB connection string, EF reference etc. Is there any better way to do it?